# Restrict SQL access

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2013

I'm building an application in C# that accesses a SQL Database.

It needs to be fully accessible but only by one person at a time, so if another user connects using the credentials within the program it will only allow them to view data and not allow them to append or insert etc..

So basically I want to achieve the equivalent of locking a Word document.

Hope that makes sense, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Brendan

Comment: That sounds like a horrible idea. But it should be simple to implement in your application. What have you tried? You haven't actually asked a question.

Comment: Seems like a _very_ pessimistic locking strategy.  What is the purpose?  Are you just worried about integrity or just being pessimistic?

Comment: Do you need to protect a single record or table from concurrency issues, if so this may not be the most appropriate approach. Read the following for ways to do optimistic and pessimistic locking http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/114262/ways-of-doing-locking-in-NET-Pessimistic-and-opt

Comment: Haha, thanks! If were up to me then it wouldn't be happening, the department it's being created for have asked for it though, seems silly but the will moan otherwise!

Comment: @Brendan Tell them to visit this webpage and see all the experienced people that have a very low opinion of people placing arbitrary and ridiculous requirements on systems.

Comment: Sorry, to answer your question - I haven't attempted anything as yet, I'm still very new to this, but I thought I'd ask to get an overview and try a few different approaches. I would like to avoid any concurrency issues if I can, having this run as smoothly as possible is the idea. Codex - thank you for the article

Comment: @Mason, that's a great idea, the only thing better would be to beat them with a keyboard. But, I may as well urinate into the wind, they won't care :(

Comment: @Mason, well..I told them that it would be a stupid idea and they're happy with that! So locking and change logging is on the agenda now, thanks for your help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

sp_getapplock is your friend at

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx

- alterantive put the db into single user mode.